# (TS - Redux) How to initialize state property as null: Type 'UserData' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm having this error: **Type 'UserData' is not assignable to type 'null'.**

I defined the user state property as **user: UserData | null;**... So i don't understand why it doesn't let me to initialize the property as null and then assign it a UserData like value:
[Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fzVT.png)

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { UserData } from "../../types/user";

interface AppState {
  user: UserData | null;
}

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState: { user: null },
  reducers: {
    loadUserIntoApp: {
      reducer(state, action: PayloadAction<UserData>) {
        state.user = action.payload; // This is the line with an error
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should infer the AppState interface to the initialState

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { UserData } from "../../types/user";

interface AppState {
  user: UserData | null;
}

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState: AppState = { user: null },
  reducers: {
    loadUserIntoApp: {
      (state, action: PayloadAction<UserData>) => { //you should add the reducer like this
        state.user = action.payload;
       }
    }
  }
})
```

go to [decumetation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#application-usage) for more info